# How can I repair a UV map?

Tags: modeling, uv

I'm essentially a complete novice at Blender and yet still decided to create a large, complex build which I wanted to texture and add to a game (ArmA 3), however I made the entire model before realizing I had not prepared to texture it once complete, so I have no seams at all, and when I went to Smart UV Unwrap, THIS is what appeared..

[image: The mess I've created..]

So now I'm afraid that I've completely ruined my chances at getting this thing textured and ready for game implementation.

I'm not able to repair this with my current knowledge and was wondering if anyone know's how to salvage it into a UV display that I can understand.

For clarification, this is the vehicle that I attempted to UV Unwrap..

[image: The vehicle I built, exact same condition as when question posted.]

Have I botched this entire model to the point where proper UV mapping isn't possible without a LOT of time?

Comment: Hi, you can delete the UV map (see the "object data" propertires tab) and try to unwrap differently... to get help with the specific model, you caould upload to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then edit your quertion pasting the provided link

Comment: watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scPSP_U858k

Comment: Unwrapping is generally done towards the end of modelling or after it, so you should be good, no need to redo anything. For simplicity's sake you may want to mark seams and unwrap identical parts only once and then copy them around in place, like wheels or symmetrical parts

Comment: I also recommend you watching a tutorial on how to unwrap your mesh in Blender. You normally do it when you finished your model so it's fine. You define the seams by selecting the edges you want to become seams. Then you press ctrl - e and after that A for "mark seams" 
Smart UV often creates UV maps like this so don't worry. 
When you have seams I think smart UV will consider them. After that you can get rid of some seams maybe by connecting the edges in the UV editor. You should do that with seams that are often easily to see.